# Problem ordering with including model in sequelize v6 [Solved] - It wasn't sequelize error

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to add order clause to method function but got this unknown column error.

`Error: Unknown column 'Product.createdAt' in 'order clause'`

So I looked up the SQL and found that **the problem is column name in order clause** that sequelize
generated.

I'll be very thankful for any idea to solve this problem.

**System**

- windows 10
- nodejs v13.11.0
- sequelize [ CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.3.4 ]

**Router**

```js
...

const models = require('./models')
const { Product, ViewItem, Category, ... } = models

...

//Middleware apply the req.filter, generated filter object will be like this

const req = {
   ...req,
   filter : {
      order : [
         [{ model : Product, as : 'Product'}, 'rating', 'desc'],
         ['createdAt', 'desc']
      ],
      ...
   }
}

const products = await ViewItem.listAndApply({
                subquery : false,
                include: [
                    { model : Brand, as : 'Brand', required: true },
                    { 
                        model : Category,
                        as : 'Category', 
                        required: true,
                        attributes : [ 'id', 'level', 'name' ],
                        where : req.filters.toJson({ namespace : 'Category' }) 
                    },
                    { model : ProductImage, as : 'ProductImage', required: false },
                    { model : ProductStatus, as : 'ProductStatus', required: false },
                    { model : ProductType, as : 'ProductType', required: false },
                    { model : ProductRating, as : 'ProductRating', required : true }
                ],
                where : req.filters.toJson(),
                limit : limit,
                offset : offset,
                order : req.filters.order
...
```

**models/ViewItem.js**

```js
ViewItem.listAndApply = async function (options) {
    const {
      ProductView,
      Product,
    } = require('.')

    const payload = lodash.cloneDeep(options)
    let {
      include,
    } = payload

    if (!include) include = []
    .
    .
    .
    const items = await ViewItem.findAll({
      subquery: false,
      include: [
        .
        .
        .
        {
          model: Product,
          as: 'Product',
          required: true,
          where: product.where,
          include: include
        }
      ],
      where: where,
      limit: limit,
      order: order
    })

    //Please don't mind the applyView(), this function do nothing with sequelize level.
    
    return items.map(item => applyView(item))
  }
```

**This SQL is broken (What I got from sequelize)**

```sql
SELECT 
  `ViewItem`.*, 
.
.
.
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      .
      .
      .
      `Product`.`rating` AS `Product.rating`, 
      .
      .
      .
    FROM 
      `ViewItems` AS `ViewItem` 
.
.
.
ORDER BY 
  `Product`.`rating` ASC,
  `ViewItem`.`createdAt` DESC;
```

**This SQL works fine (What I want to generate)**

```sql
SELECT 
  `ViewItem`.*, 
.
.
.
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      .
      .
      .
      `Product`.`rating` AS `Product.rating`, 
      .
      .
      .
    FROM 
      `ViewItems` AS `ViewItem` 
.
.
.
ORDER BY 
  `Product.rating` ASC,
  `ViewItem`.`createdAt` DESC;
```

What I tried to solve this problem.

```js
// SQL broken with syntax error, col name return is " ``. "
req.filter.order.push([sequelize.literal('Product.rating'), 'desc'])

// also broken with same error above
req.filter.order.push([sequelize.col('Product.rating'), 'desc'])

// same
```

I'm
Any idea for resolving this error?

---

### Model Code added

**models/Product.js**

```js
'use strict'

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    sku: DataTypes.STRING,
    supplier: DataTypes.STRING,
    manufacturer: DataTypes.STRING,
    thumbnail: DataTypes.STRING,
    wholeSalePrice: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    retailPrice: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    originalPrice: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    discount: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    domestic: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true
    },
    underAge: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true
    },
    display: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true
    },
    views: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    reviews : {
      type : DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue : 0
    },
    jjim : {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    sold: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    rating: {
      type: DataTypes.FLOAT,
      defaultValue: 0
    }
  }, { timestamps: true, paranoid: true })

  Product.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    Product.belongsToMany(models.Category, { as: 'Category', through: 'ProductCategory', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    Product.belongsToMany(models.ProductView, { as: 'ProductView', through: 'ProductViewMap', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    Product.belongsTo(models.Brand, { as: 'Brand' })
    Product.hasMany(models.ProductImage, { as: 'ProductImage', foreignKey: 'ProductId' , onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    Product.hasMany(models.ProductItem, { as: 'ProductItem', foreignKey: 'ProductId', onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    Product.belongsTo(models.ProductStatus, { as: 'ProductStatus' })
    Product.belongsTo(models.ProductType, { as: 'ProductType' })
    Product.hasOne(models.ProductRating, { foreignKey : 'ProductId', as : 'ProductRating' })
    Product.hasMany(models.UserJjim, { as : 'Jjims'})
  }

  Product.afterCreate(async (product, option) =>{
    const {
      sequelize,
      Product,
      ProductViewMap,
      ViewItem,
      ProductRating
    } = require('.')

    const { id, name, thumbnail } = product
    const DEFAULT_VIEW = 1

    // await ProductViewMap.create({ ProductId : id, ProductViewId : DEFAULT_VIEW })
    const item = await ViewItem.create({ ProductId : id, ProductViewId : DEFAULT_VIEW })
    console.log(item)
    await ProductRating.create({ ProductId : id })
  })

  Product.prototype.findActiveItem = async function(){
    const { ViewItem, View } = require('.')

    return ViewItem.findOne({
      subquery : false,
      include : [
        { model : View, as : 'View', required : true }
      ],
      where : {
        display : true,
        ProductId : this.id
      }
    })
  }

  Product.prototype.findActiveView = async function(){
    const { ViewItem, View } = require('.')

    return View.findOne({
      subquery: false,
      include : [
        { 
          model : View, 
          as : 'View', 
          required : true,
          include : [
            {
              model : ViewItem,
              as : 'ViewItem',
              required : true,
              where : {
                display : true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
  }

  return Product
}
```

**models/ViewItem.js**

```js
'use strict'

const lodash = require('lodash')

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const ViewItem = sequelize.define('ViewItem', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    thumbnail: DataTypes.STRING,
    retailPrice: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    discount: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    staticDiscount: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    promotion: {
      type: DataTypes.JSON,
      defaultValue: null
    },
    position: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    display: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
    timestamps: true,
    paranoid: true
  })

  ViewItem.associate = function (models) {
    // associations can be defined here
    ViewItem.belongsTo(models.ProductView, {
      as: 'ProductView',
      foreignKey: 'ProductViewId',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })
    ViewItem.belongsTo(models.Product, {
      as: 'Product',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })
  }

  /* Hook */
  ViewItem.afterCreate(async function (item) {
    const {
      Product,
      ProductViewMap
    } = require('.')

    const {
      id,
      ProductId,
      ProductViewId
    } = item

    /* Join table에 row를 추가합니다 */
    await ProductViewMap.create({
      ProductId,
      ProductViewId
    })

    /* View 아이템중에 같은 Product를 가르키는 상품의 노출 설정을 false로 합니다. */
    const product = await Product.findOne({
      where: {
        id: ProductId
      }
    })

    await ViewItem.update({
      display: false,
    }, {
      where: {
        ProductId: ProductId
      }
    })

    /* 생성되는 ViewItem의 초기 display 속성은 Product의 display를 따릅니다. */
    await this.update({
      display: product.display
    }, {
      where: {
        id: id
      }
    })
  })

  ViewItem.listAndApply = async function (options) {
    const {
      ProductView,
      Product,
    } = require('.')

    const payload = lodash.cloneDeep(options)
    let {
      include,
      where,
      order,
      limit,
      offset,
      product
    } = payload

    if (!include) include = []
    if (!product) product = {}

    where = where ? where : null
    order = order ? order : null
    limit = limit ? limit : null
    offset = offset ? offset : null
    product.where = product.where ? product.where : null

    const items = await ViewItem.findAll({
      subquery: false,
      include: [{
          model: ProductView,
          as: 'ProductView',
          required: true
        },
        {
          model: Product,
          as: 'Product',
          required: true,
          where: product.where,
          include: include
        }
      ],
      where: where,
      limit: limit,
      order: order
    })

    return items.map(item => applyView(item))
  }

  return ViewItem
}


/* private function */
const applyView = (item) => {
  if (!item) return null
  if (!item.Product) return null
  if (!item.ProductView) return null

  const product = lodash.cloneDeep(item.Product.toJSON())
  const view = lodash.cloneDeep(item.ProductView.toJSON())
  /* 
    View를 적용합니다.
  
    #1. 가격정보를 수정합니다.
    #2. 스티커와 태그를 추가합니다.
    #3. 상세페이지 url을 추가합니다.
  */

  if (view.additionalDiscount) {
    const discount = product.discount + view.additionalDiscount
    const retailPrice = Math.floor(product.originalPrice * (1 - discount / 100))

    product.discount = discount
    product.retailPrice = retailPrice
  } else if (view.discount) {
    const retailPrice = Math.floor(product.retailPrice * (1 - view.discount / 100))
    const discount = Math.floor((1 - retailPrice / product.originalPrice) * 100)

    product.retailPrice = retailPrice
    product.discount = discount
  }

  if (view.staticDiscount) {
    const retailPrice = product.retailPrice - view.staticDiscount
    const discount = Math.floor((1 - retailPrice / product.originalPrice) * 100)

    product.retailPrice = retailPrice
    product.discount = discount
  }

  if (view.tag) product.tag = view.tag

  if (view.sticker) product.sticker = sticker

  product.detailUrl = view.detailUrl ? `${view.detailUrl}/${item.id}` : `/products/${item.id}`

  /*
    ViewItem 

    #1. 상품정보를 수정합니다.
    #2. 가격정보를 수정합니다.
    #3. retailPrice가 있다면 기존 계산값을 무시하고 이 값을 사용합니다.
  */

  if (item.name) product.name = item.name
  if (item.thumbnail) product.thumbnail = item.thumbnail
  if (item.description) product.description = item.description

  if (item.discount) {}
  if (item.staticDiscount) {}

  if (item.retailPrice) product.retailPrice = item.retailPrice

  return ({
    ...product,
    ProductView: view,
    id: item.id,
    ProductId: item.ProductId,
    ProductViewId: item.ProductViewId
  })
}
```

Full code is about 500 lines, I reduced some unrelacted part for readability.
Other models are not related with order clause.

Comment: Please share the migration code if you are using and please share the model code.

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try below for order sequelize literal:

```
req.filter.order.push([sequelize.literal(`"Product.rating"`), 'desc'])
// OR
req.filter.order.push([sequelize.literal("`Product.rating`"), 'desc'])
```

Comment: Both "`Procut.rating`" and `"Product.rating"` doesn't work for me. 
both are producing  " ``. DESC " for my order clause.

Any other solution for adding literal query in order clause? if so, should I querying via query interface is my only option for working this out?

Comment: Sorry bro. My problem wasn't in sequelize itself but my instance method. I copied option object before querying to prevent mutation of option object, using lodash.deepClone. But it turns out to that even deepClone cannot copy the prototype chain. I checked this with `sequelize.literal('Product.rating') instanceof sequelize.Utils.SequelizeMethod` and `copied instaceof sequelize.Utils.SequelizeMethod`. That is the reason why I got `Error: Order must be type of array or instance of a valid sequelize method.`. Thanks for you effort @Abishek Shah

Comment: it did work for me to ordering by an include model field.

Answer (score 0):

My problem wasn't in sequelize itself but my instance method.
I copied option object before querying to prevent mutation of option object, using `lodash.cloneDeep()`. But it turns out to that even deep clone can't copy the prototype chain.

```js
const payload = lodash.cloneDeep(options)//I massed up in here
```

I can demonstrate it by executing code below.

```js
const sequelize = require('sequelize')
const lodash = require('lodash')

const orginal = sequelize.literal('Product.rating')
const copied = lodash.cloneDeep(original)

console.log(original instanceof sequelize.Utils.SequelizeMethod )//true
console.log(copied instanceof sequelize.Utils.SequelizeMethod)//false
```

That is the reason why I got

```
Error: Order must be type of array or instance of a valid sequelize method.
```

Because `copied`  object has no prototype chain pointing `SequelizeMethod`, inside of sequlieze query generator, the process failed to match my literal query and it leaded for me to getting broken query.

In the meantime, I still can't resolve unknown column name error in order clause when passing array for `option.order` argument. I took a look in `abstract/query-generator.js` briefly, and got some insight to resolve this problem. Generating order clause in `getQueryOrders()`, it would be even better than now, if order query generator refer the selected column name.

```sql
SELECT 
  `ViewItem`.*, 
.
.
.
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      .
      .
      .
      `Product`.`rating` AS `Product.rating`,
      #this column name should be equal to order clause's column name
      .
      .
      .
    FROM 
      `ViewItems` AS `ViewItem` 
.
.
.
ORDER BY 
  `Product`.`rating` ASC,#otherwise, it invokes unknow column name error.
  `ViewItem`.`createdAt` DESC;

# Then how about referring the selected column name in the where and order clause
# instead of managing each clause loosely?
```

Comment: If you still want cloning the object, you can try using npm rfdc - https://www.npmjs.com/package/rfdc. The documentation says it also clones the prototype & properties. I have not tried it myself, but it can be worth the try.

Comment: I think cloning object still be useful since it can prevent to mutate original object. Sounds I could use that. Thanks for letting me know @AbhishekShah